# Repository Pattern Standardization of methods

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern

All I am trying to find out the correct definition of the repository pattern.

My original understanding was this (extremely dumbed down)

- Separate your Business Objects from your Data Objects
- Standardize access methods in data access layer.

I have really seen 2 different implementation, and there are no formal examples online, the ones i have seen are tucked away in books.

**Implementation 1 :**

```
public Interface IRepository<T>{
      List<T> GetAll();
      void Create(T p);
      void Update(T p);
}


public interface IProductRepository: IRepository<Product> {
      //Extension methods if needed
       List<Product> GetProductsByCustomerID();
}
```

---

**Implementation 2 :**

```
public interface IProductRepository {
      List<Product> GetAllProducts();
      void CreateProduct(Product p);
      void UpdateProduct(Product p);
      List<Product> GetProductsByCustomerID();
}
```

Notice the first is generic Get/Update/GetAll, etc, the second is more of what I would define "DAO" like.

Both share an extraction from your data entities.  Which I like, but i can do the same with a simple DAO.  However the second piece standardize access operations I see value in, if you implement this enterprise wide people would easily know the set of access methods for your repository.

Am I wrong to assume that the standardization of access to data is an integral piece of this pattern ?   If both are correct why would one choose to do implementation 2?

[Rhino](http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/08/the-repository-pattern.aspx) has a good article on implementation 1, and of course MS has a vague [definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee413961.aspx) and an example of implementation 2 is [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2008/04/24/what-purpose-does-the-repository-pattern-have.aspx).

Comment: To me an _interface_ is an abstraction, i.e. the opposite of an _implementation_. Are we discussing just the interfaces here, or rather the implementing classes?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I second the Fowler quote cited by oded. I want to point out that he said "collection-*like*" interface. How you implement the collection like interface is certainly up to you, but neither can nor should you try to hide the fact it represents a remote datasource. It therefore differs significantly from an in-memory collection, which does not need to flush changes to a remote data store. The change tracking mechanism of your ORM or your roll-your-own solution determines how transparent this can be made to the caller. Deletes usually need to be marked explicitly, inserts are discoverable (persistence by reachability) and updates sometimes need to be marked explicitly too. Combine this with the complicated dependencies of your aggregate roots and you'll see that's not very collection like.

There is no such thing as "the cannonical repository implementation".

There is a constant battle going on between the advocators of a generic repository base class and those who prefer implementing each repository on its own. While the generic implementation is appealing in simple scenarios, you will very often find it to be a very leaky abstraction. For example some of your aggregates may only be soft-deleted (cistomizable via virtual method overrides) while others may not support a delete operation at all.

Make sure you understand the implications of each approach before deciding which route to take. Greg Young has a good post on the merits of generic repositories.

https://web.archive.org/web/20090204223739/http://codebetter.com/blogs/gregyoung/archive/2009/01/16/ddd-the-generic-repository.aspx

Comment: The whole point of the Repository is to abstract away persistence-related concepts.  Some of these are typically placed into the Unit of Work which need only be used in your infrastructure to automatically flush changes after your application code handles the request.

If your repository looks like a DAO, you're just doing DAO all over again, which is not the point.

Answer (score 8):

From Martin Fowler "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture", the definition of the Repository Pattern is:

> Mediates between the domain and data mapping layers using a collection-like interface for accessing domain objects.

So, both approaches are correct.

Comment: i guess the whole "collection-like" is to vague, i would argue that collection like would mean Get/Update/Remove/etc not.. but i am assuming you would argue the same that Get = GetProduct

Answer (score 3):

I am a great fan of the generic repository pattern but I think you should strongly consider not directly inheriting from the interface as it can become a very large limitation especially since many times the code for the generic interface will be the same that it could be defined in an abstract base class that you will no longer be able to have more than 1 generic repository inside a class.

I recommend having your IProductRepository implementer access the generic `IRepository<Product>` through delegation and inject that in through the constructor so you can compose your class of possibly many IRepositories and group them behind a single interface in a way that makes sense.

I wrote a blog on this topic while it specifically references NHibernate this pattern can be applied to any type of repository: [Creating a common generic and extensible NHiberate Repository version 2](http://dotnetchris.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/creating-a-common-generic-and-extensible-nhiberate-repository-version-2/)

Answer (score 2):

With the introduction of LINQ in .NET, a generic repository pattern becomes much easier to realize:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IQueryable<T>
{
    void Add(T item);
    void Remove(T item);
}
```

To qualify as a repository, it merely needs to be able to access data in the underlying store (easily provided by `IQueryable`) and modify the contained data.

You can provide extensions to the base interface to provide hooks for more entity-specific behaviour (such as wiring into a stored procedure call for a SQL-based repository), but the majority of operations can be completed by the simple interface.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your generic repository interface (implementation 1) and your variation on the role-specific repository (implementation 2) you can also consider a generic method repository:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    void Save<ENTITY>(ENTITY entity) where ENTITY : DomainEntity;

    ENTITY Load<ENTITY>(Guid id) where ENTITY : DomainEntity;

    IQueryable<ENTITY> Query<ENTITY>() where ENTITY : DomainEntity;

    IQueryable<ENTITY> Query<ENTITY>(IDomainQuery<ENTITY> whereQuery)
        where ENTITY : DomainEntity;
}
```

This third version comes from [this blogpost](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/09/02/ddd-repository-implementation-patterns.aspx) by Jimmy Bogard, where he also expresses preference for the generic repository interface.
I usually follow that with a generic repository baseclass which implements this interface; that way, I only have to implement the stuff that is different for each domain entity.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the generic repository with composition instead of inheritance. That gives me the advantage of a generic implementation, with the control of which methods to expose.

Something like this:

```
public Interface IRepository<T>{
  List<T> GetAll();
  void Create(T p);
  void Update(T p);
}


public interface IProductRepository {
  //Extension methods if needed
   List<Product> GetProductsByCustomerID();
   List<T> GetAll();
   void Create(T p);
   //Let assume here you should not be able to update the products
}

public ProductRepository : IProductRepository {
    private IRepository _repository;

    public ProductRepository(IRepository repository) {
        this._repository = repository;
    }

       List<T> GetAll() 
       {
            _repository.GetAll();
       }

       void Create(T p) 
       {
            _repository.Create(p);
       }

       List<Product> GetProductsByCustomerID() 
       {
          //..implementation goes here
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The repository pattern is one of the most used pattern in software development. The are many post that can be marked as answer to your question.
Something that i like to highlight is the fact that a good repository implementation will be improved if you use IoC (Autofac, Windsor, etc...). I have been playing long time ago with some ADO.NET based frameworks (LinqToSql, EF) and NHibernate. You always can have benefits from a generic implementation if you use IoC.
You can define interfaces for your specific repositories and resolve when you really need some specific actions.